# Why do builds for various projects fail with ‘Operation not permitted’ using iOS on-device compiler/toolchain?

Tags: ios, build, gnu-make, jailbreak, llvm-clang

I am an intermediately skilled Linux/Unix user trying to compile software for an iPad on a (jailbroken) iPad.

Many builds (for example, make and tex-live) fail with some `Operation not permitted` error. This will either look like `Can't exec "blah": Operation not permitted` or `execvp: blah: Operation not permitted` where `blah` is `aclocal`, a `configure` script, `libtool`, or just about anything. Curiously, finding the offending line in a `Makefile` or `configure` script and prefixing it with `sudo -u mobile -E` will solve the error for that line, only for it to reappear for on a later line or in another file. Since I am running the build scripts as `mobile`, I do not understand how this could possibly fix the issue, yet it does. I have confirmed that making these changes does actually allow for the script to work successfully up to that point.  Running the build script with `sudo` or `sudo -u mobile -E` and/or running the entire build as `root` does not solve the issue; with either, I still must edit build scripts to add `sudo`’s.

I would like to know why this is happening, and if possible how I could address the issue without editing build scripts. Any information about these types of errors would be interesting to me even if they do not solve my problem. I am aware that the permissions/security/entitlements system is unusual on iOS and would like to learn more about how it works.

I am using an iPad Pro 4 on jailbroken iOS 13.5 with the build tools from sbingner’s and MCApollo’s repos (repo.bingner.com and mcapollo.github.io/Public). In particular, I am using a build of LLVM 5 (manually installed from sbingner’s old debs), Clang 10, Darwin CC tools 927 and GNU Make 4.2.1. I have set `CC`, `CXX`, `CFLAGS`, etc. to point to `clang-10` and my iOS 13.5 SDK with `-isysroot` and have confirmed that these settings are working. I would like to replace these with updated versions, but I cannot yet build these tools for myself due to this issue and a few others. I do have access to a Mac for cross-compilation if necessary, but I would rather use only my iPad because I like the challenge.

I can attach any logs necessary or provide more information if that would be useful; I do not know enough about this issue to know what information is useful. Thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: Sounds like the sandbox colliding with shebangs. Unfortunately shebangs/interpreters are third-class citizens on iOS, and there's only so much jailbreaks can do to change that. To get the exact reason it's failing, you should be able to filter syslog for `kernel(Sandbox)` while running the scripts in question.

Comment: The logs gave a small hint. These messages aren't timed correctly (seconds off) with the errors I'm seeing, but it could be `Sandbox: bash(pid) System Policy: deny(1) process-exec-interpreter /bin/bash` or occasionally `/usr/bin/perl` which makes sense since aclocal is a perl script. This supports that problem is shebangs, but it's weird that `sudo -u mobile`ing works around the issue. I suspect that the issue is shebangs calling other shebangs. Is there any chance of solving this without making edits in the configure scripts? Maybe patching bash, exec(vp), or other programs calling exec?

Comment: The bash currently shipped with the bootstrap should already do that, but other programs might not. Either patching the sandbox profile in-kernel or hooking `_execve` and `posix_spawn` system-wide should make it work. But yeah I had a chat with Sam Bingner, and we both consider the current behaviour a bug. He plans to implement a system-wide userland hook for unc0ver, and I'm gonna attempt to write a kernel patch for checkra1n.

Comment: That's great! Thanks for helping!

Comment: @siguza any updates? This process-exec-interpreter is still a major issue for anyone doing on-device development even on unc0ver 6.2.0. Using checkra1n absolutely solves everything, including the extremely annoying “library validation overridden” endless errors that always clog dmesg on unc0ver. All devices all iOS I’ve tried. 12.4 and 13.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who ends up needing to address this issue on a jailbreak that does not have a fix for this issue, I have written (pasted below) a userland hook based on the `posix_spawn` implementation from the source of Apple’s xnu kernel.

Compile it with Theos, and inject it into all processes spawned by your shell by setting environment variable `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` to the path of the resulting dylib. Note: some tweak injectors (namely libhooker, see [here](https://github.com/ProcursusTeam/Procursus/issues/229)) reset `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`, so if you notice this behavior, be sure to inject only your library.

Because the implementation of the exec syscalls in iOS call out to `posix_spawn`, this hook fixes all of the exec-related issue’s I’ve run into so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <spawn.h>

// Copied from bsd/kern/kern_exec.c
#define IS_WHITESPACE(ch) ((ch == ' ') || (ch == '\t'))
#define IS_EOL(ch) ((ch == '#') || (ch == '\n'))
// Copied from bsd/sys/imgact.h
#define IMG_SHSIZE 512

// Here, we provide an alternate implementation of posix_spawn which correctly handles #!.
// This is based on the implementation of posix_spawn in bsd/kern/kern_exec.c from Apple's xnu source.
// Thus, I am fairly confident that this posix_spawn has correct behavior relative to macOS.
%hookf(int, posix_spawn, pid_t *pid, const char *orig_path, const posix_spawn_file_actions_t *file_actions, const posix_spawnattr_t *attrp, char *const orig_argv[], char *const envp[]) {
    
    // Call orig before checking for anything.
    // This mirrors the standard implementation of posix_spawn because it first checks if we are spawning a binary.
    int err = %orig;
    
    // %orig returns EPERM when spawning a script.
    // Thus, if err is anything other than EPERM, we can just return like normal.
    if (err != EPERM) 
        return err;
    
    // At this point, we do not need to check for exec permissions or anything like that.
    //  because posix_spawn would have returned that error instead of EPERM.

    // Now we open the file for reading so that we can check if it's a script.
    // If it turns out not to be a script, the EPERM must be from something else
    //  so we just return err.

    FILE *file = fopen(orig_path, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        return err;
    }
    if (fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET)) {
        return err;
    }   

    // In exec_activate_image, the data buffer is filled with the first PAGE_SIZE bytes of the file.
    // However, in exec_shell_imgact, only the first IMG_SHSIZE bytes are used.
    // Thus, we read IMG_SHSIZE bytes out of our file.
    // The buffer is filled with newlines so that if the file is not IMG_SHSIZE bytes,
    //  the logic reads an IS_EOL.
    char vdata[IMG_SHSIZE] = {'\n'};
    if (fread(vdata, 1, IMG_SHSIZE, file) < 2) { // If we couldn't read at least two bytes, it's not a script.
        fclose(file);
        return err;
    }

    // Now that we've filled the buffer, we don't need the file anymore.
    fclose(file);
    
    // Now we follow exec_shell_imgact.
    // The point of this is to confirm we have a script 
    //  and extract the usable part of the interpreter+arg string.
    // Where they return -1, we don't have a shell script, so we return err.
    // Where they return an error, we return that same error.
    // We don't bother doing any SUID stuff because SUID scripts should be disabled anyway.
        char *ihp;
        char *line_startp, *line_endp;
        
    // Make sure we have a shell script.
        if (vdata[0] != '#' || vdata[1] != '!') {
        return err;
    }
        
        // Try to find the first non-whitespace character
        for (ihp = &vdata[2]; ihp < &vdata[IMG_SHSIZE]; ihp++) {
                if (IS_EOL(*ihp)) {
                        // Did not find interpreter, "#!\n"
                        return ENOEXEC;
                } else if (IS_WHITESPACE(*ihp)) {
                        // Whitespace, like "#!    /bin/sh\n", keep going.
                } else {
                        // Found start of interpreter
                        break;
                }
        }
        
        if (ihp == &vdata[IMG_SHSIZE]) {
                // All whitespace, like "#!           "
                return ENOEXEC;
        }

        line_startp = ihp;
        
        // Try to find the end of the interpreter+args string
        for (; ihp < &vdata[IMG_SHSIZE]; ihp++) {
                if (IS_EOL(*ihp)) {
                        // Got it
                        break;
                } else {
                        // Still part of interpreter or args
                }
        }
        
        if (ihp == &vdata[IMG_SHSIZE]) {
                // A long line, like "#! blah blah blah" without end
                return ENOEXEC;
        }
        
        // Backtrack until we find the last non-whitespace
        while (IS_EOL(*ihp) || IS_WHITESPACE(*ihp)) {
                ihp--;
        }
        
        // The character after the last non-whitespace is our logical end of line
        line_endp = ihp + 1;
        
        /*
         * Now we have pointers to the usable part of:
         *
         * "#!  /usr/bin/int first    second   third    \n"
         *      ^ line_startp                       ^ line_endp
         */

    // Now, exec_shell_imgact copies the interpreter into another buffer and then null-terminates it.
    // Then, it copies the entire interpreter+args into another buffer and null-terminates it for later processing into argv.
    // This processing is done in exec_extract_strings, which goes through and null-terminates each argument.
    // We will just do this all at once since that's much easier.
    
    // Keep track of how many arguments we have.
    int i_argc = 0;

    ihp = line_startp;
    while (true) {
        // ihp is on the start of an argument.
        i_argc++;
        // Scan to the end of the argument.
        for (; ihp < line_endp; ihp++) {
            if (IS_WHITESPACE(*ihp)) {
                // Found the end of the argument
                break;
            } else {
                // Keep going
            } 
        }
        // Null terminate the argument
        *ihp = '\0';
        // Scan to the beginning of the next argument.
        for (; ihp < line_endp; ihp++) {
            if (!IS_WHITESPACE(*ihp)) {
                // Found the next argument
                break;
            } else {
                // Keep going
            }
        }
        if (ihp == line_endp) {
            // We've reached the end of the arg string
            break;
        }
        // If we are here, ihp is the start of an argument.
    }
    // Now line_startp is a bunch of null-terminated arguments possibly padded by whitespace.
    // i_argc is now the count of the interpreter arguments.
       
    // Our new argv should look like i_argv[0], i_argv[1], i_argv[2], ..., orig_path, orig_argv[1], orig_argv[2], ..., NULL
    //  where i_argv is the arguments to be extracted from line_startp;
    // To allocate our new argv, we need to know orig_argc.
    int orig_argc = 0;
    while (orig_argv[orig_argc] != NULL) {
        orig_argc++;
    }
    
    // We need space for i_argc + 1 + (orig_argc - 1) + 1 char*'s
    char *argv[i_argc + orig_argc + 1];
    
    // Copy i_argv into argv
    int i = 0;
    ihp = line_startp;
    for (; i < i_argc; i++) {
        // ihp is on the start of an argument
        argv[i] = ihp;
        // Scan to the next null-terminator
        for (; ihp < line_endp; ihp++) {
            if (*ihp == '\0') {
                // Found it
                break;
            } else {
                // Keep going
            }
        }
        // Go to the next character
        ihp++;
        // Then scan to the next argument. 
        // There must be another argument because we already counted i_argc.
        for (; ihp < line_endp; ihp++) {
            if (!IS_WHITESPACE(*ihp)) {
                // Found it
                break;
            } else {
                // Keep going
            }
        }
        // ihp is on the start of an argument.
    }

    // Then, copy orig_path into into argv.
    // We need to make a copy of orig_path to avoid issues with const.
    char orig_path_copy[strlen(orig_path)+1];
    strcpy(orig_path_copy, orig_path);  
    argv[i] = orig_path_copy;
    i++;

    // Now, copy orig_argv[1...] into argv.
    for (int j = 1; j < orig_argc; i++, j++) {
        argv[i] = orig_argv[j];
    }
    // Finally, add the null.
    argv[i] = NULL;
    // Now, our argv is setup correctly. 

    // Now, we can call out to posix_spawn again.
    // The interpeter is in argv[0], so we use that for the path.
    return %orig(pid, argv[0], file_actions, attrp, argv, envp);
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a million. I googled after battling this for months and at first I thought your post here was perhaps written by myself months prior, lol!